# How can I disable a button after click

Tags: javascript

I am using the following script to set my colors:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (localStorage.buttonColor) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = localStorage.buttonColor
    }
    function getButtonColor(buttonName) {
        localStorage.buttonColor = buttonName;
        document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = buttonName
    }
</script>
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<form class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
   <button name="darkBlue" onclick="getButtonColor(this.name)">Blue</button>
   <button name="black" onclick="getButtonColor(this.name)">Black</button>
</form>
```

How can I make it so that when a color is chosen that the button to select that color is 
disabled so that It cannot be selected again? Then when another button is clicked the other(s) are enabled. Also I need to set the button that's chosen from localstorage to disabled. Sorry I didn't not mention this fully in the question earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to other answers (just send the button in the handler), you can use this when initially setting the color from localStorage (assuming your 'form' is the first child of 'body'):

```
if (localStorage.buttonColor) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = localStorage.buttonColor
    var buttons = document.body.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].getElementsByTagName('button')
    for(var i =0; i < buttons.length; i++)
        if(buttons[i].name == localStorage.buttonColor) button.disabled = true
}
```

Although you might want to consider using jQuery if you often need to find elements in your code, since the getElementsByTagName selections can get verbose.

Comment: We're marking this correct as it's the only solution that checks for local storage and changes the button state to disabled and the others to enabled. It's still not quite what we wanted so my team mate opened up another question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getButtonColor(button) {
    button.disabled = "disabled"
    localStorage.buttonColor = button.name;
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = button.name
}
```

and simply send `this`:

```
<button name="darkBlue" onclick="getButtonColor(this)">Blue</button>
<button name="black" onclick="getButtonColor(this)">Black</button>
```

---

<sub>`<disclaimer> inline javascript is evil</disclaimer>`</sub>

Comment: You could also switch `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]` with `document.documentElement`.

Comment: @gdoron - Thanks but this I don't think will address if that button color is stored in localstorage and selected when the page loads. Also the solution disables the click if I click the button but if the other button is clicked I need the first one enabled otherwise it doesn't work any more.

Comment: @Marilou, yes, when you update your question obviously the answers get out of sync...

Comment: @gdoron - Hello. Sorry about that but not really a change just a clarification. I mean taking your implementation it's really only going to work for one click and after that my page won't work any more. I was thinking that would be clear from the code so I did not spell that out. Again sorry for the update. Now I am not really sure how to handle it. Should I open another question? Let me know what you think. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use :

```
function getButtonColor(button) {        
var elem=documentt.getElementById(button.id);
elem.removeAttribute("onclick");
}
```

Comment: Your solution does not make the button disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Preferred is to use **this** and bind it to a variable (often that). 
In this you get the html-object who called the function.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```
 function getButtonColor() {
        var that = this; 
        localStorage.buttonColor = that.Name;
        document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = that.Name; 
        that.disabled = "disabled"; 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but this I don't think will address if that button color is stored in localstorage and selected when the page loads. Also I need to have it so that if another button is clicked the remaining need to be all enabled.